# How to fix "..not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'float' "

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I'm trying to run a loop with a function, but I get and error. I'm new to Python, so I'm not sure why I can't apply the loop to a dict.

Here is the code:

```
def run_levenshtein(x):
    hits = []
    print(x)
    scores = {}

    for s1 in x.sequence[x.mc>0]:
        print(s1)
        scores[s1] = {}

        for s2 in x.sequence[x.mc==0]:
           print(s1 + "_" + s2)
           scores[s1][s2] = Levenshtein.seqratio(s1,s2)

           if scores > 0.8:
           hits.append([s1,s2])
        print(scores)

    return scores

 seqr = missed_cleavages.groupby('accession').apply(lambda x: run_levenshtein(x))
```

The error message:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'float'
```

I would expect a dict with the sequences with similarity score > 0.8.

Thanks.

Comment: `scores` is a dictionary, how do you compare it? do you want to compare a specific value? a sum of the values?

Comment: `if scores[s1][s2] > 0.8:`

Comment: It's probably clearer to assign a separate variable to your seqratio, compare that to 0.8, and only *then* add it to the dict: `ratio = Levenshtein.seqratio(s1,s2);  if ratio > 0.8: hits.append([s1, s2]);  scores[s1][s2] = ratio`.